# How are javascript variables "hoisted" in these examples from MDN

Tags: javascript

In [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) mozilla article, I read:

> Another unusual thing about variables in JavaScript is that you can refer to a variable declared later, without getting an exception. This concept is known as hoisting; variables in JavaScript are in a sense "hoisted" or lifted to the top of the function or statement. However, variables that aren't initialized yet will return a value of undefined.

And then some examples:

```
/**
 * Example 1
 */
console.log(x === undefined); // logs "true"
var x = 3;


/**
 * Example 2
 */
// will return a value of undefined
var myvar = "my value";

(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = "local value";
})();
```

> Example 2, above, will be interpreted the same as:

```
var myvar = "my value";

(function() {
  var myvar;
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  myvar = "local value";
})();
```

I fail to see anything being "hoisted"—at least not in the sense that I traditionally interpret the definition of the word: it seems like variables are `undefined` until after they are declared. In what sense can you "refer to a variable declared later"?

Comment: The "this variable is declared in this scope semantics" are hoisted; *assignments are not moved*. Without hoisting (which would make it a different language :D), the 2nd example would refer to the *outer* `myvar` in the log statement. As it is now, it refers to the *inner* `myvar` which *shadows* the outer variables; the value is just undefined at the time of the log statement - hoisting does not affect assignments.

Comment: @pst Okay. bear with me as the fog eventually lifts... Can I ask you what you mean "shadows" the outer variable?

Comment: "To momentarily cover" - it prevents the original [outer-scoped variable] from being seen/used :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `var` it is "hoisted" to the top of the function declaration.  Let's look at the second example again:

```
var myvar = "my value";

(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = "local value";
})();
```

Notice how `var myvar = 'my value'` is declared *first*.  Next, within the function scope, `console.log(myvar)` is called.  The result is "undefined."  Why?  You'd think it would be "my value" because that's the order that the code is in.

Because the local variable `var myvar` in the function scope is hoisted, it's not defined.  This is essentially equivalent to writing the function like this:

```
(function() {
  var myvar;
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  myvar = "local value";
})();
```

Comment: So `var myvar` is understood to be hoisted in the function's scope because it's declared outside of the function, or inside?

Comment: @matthewpavkov because it's declared inside.  I'm sure you know that "hoisted" means "lifted up."  So imagine the line `var myvar` is "lifted up" to the top of the inside of the function scope.

Comment: Starting to sort of understand it. Thank you. I just don't understand how `var myvar = "my value";` declared immediately before `(function() {
  var myvar;........` in Example 2, that is, its value being declared globally (outside that immediate function directly below) isn't maintained "into" the immediate function. why wouldn't the `console.log(myvar); // undefined` not be `my value`?

Comment: Also, can you show me a practical example of how this knowledge could be implemented usefully? Thank you so much.

Comment: @thomas the declaration of `var myvar` outside the function scope has *nothing* to do with hoisting.  It's simply done to illustrate the example.  If you remove the `var myvar` from the function above, `console.log(myvar)` will say `"my value"` instead

Comment: @thomas it's not something that is to be used handily, it's just part of JavaScript used to prevent errors.  You should *always* declare your variables at the top of the current scope and never rely on hoisting.

Comment: But just to be clear, that hoisted variable within the function is resetting the global variable to undefined. It's so weird. It hoists the declaration of the variable, but not the value that's assigned to it? Can I describe it like this?

Comment: @thomas just look at the second example I posted in my answer.  That's exactly how it works without any hoisting magic

Comment: Absotively Posilutely. Thanks again.