# Strange javascript scoping issue

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var c = 1;

function myFunction(){
    c = 2;
    var c = 4;
    console.log(c);
}

console.log(c);
myFunction();
console.log(c);
```

Why is the last console.log spitting out 1? Here is how it is supposed to work in my brain:

```
var c = 1; // create global variable called 'c'

function myFunction(){
    c = 2; // assign value of global 'c' to 2
    var c = 4; // create a new variable called 'c' which has a new address in memory (right?)  with a value of 4
    console.log(c); // log the newly created 'c' variable (which has the value of 4)
}

console.log(c); //log the global c
myFunction(); //log the internal c
console.log(c); //log the updated global c
```

Comment: That is because you are redeclaring `var c` in the function scope. Remove the `var` inside the `function` and it should be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scope where your console.log runs, only the global variable exists. And the function never touches the global variable.

The details:

```
var c = 1; // create global variable called 'c'

function myFunction(){
    // the global is unavailable here, as you declared a local c.
    // Its declaration is hoisted to the top of the function, so
    // c exists here, and its value is undefined.
    c = 2; // assign value of local 'c' to 2
    var c = 4; // change local c to 4
    console.log(c); // log local c (4)
}

console.log(c); //log the global c
myFunction(); //log the internal c
console.log(c); //log the global c (which never changed)
```

Due to the hoisting mentioned above, your function behaves as if the code was:

```
function myFunction(){
    var c; // declares a local c that shadows the global one
    c = 2;
    c = 4;
    console.log(c);
}
```

#### Some references about hoisting

- [MDN page for the `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- [MDN scope cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)
- [How are javascript variables "hoisted" in these examples from MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806135/how-are-javascript-variables-hoisted-in-these-examples-from-mdn)
- [Javascript hoisting explained](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/20/javascript-hoisting-explained/)
- [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: c = 2; // assign value of local 'c' to 2

I believe you are incorrect, this is the global c I created outside of the function

Comment: No, it isn't, the declaration is hoisted to the top.

Comment: if I log c within the function without re-assigning the value I still get 1 though, how does that work if it's not the global c?

Comment: That is only true if you remove the `var` keyword from the function (then there is no local variable anymore). @Tai

Comment: Ok I think I got it now, that is very interesting.. thank you for the response!

Comment: The moral of the story is that if you declare a var anywhere within a function, its scope is the whole of the innermost function its that contains the declaration of the var.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Yes, that's probably a much better way to put it than what I said.

Comment: What I meant to say was: The moral of the story is that, if you declare a variable anywhere within a function, the scope of the variable is the whole of the innermost function which contains the declaration of the variable.