# Javascript Odd Scoping Behavior

Tags: javascript, scoping

I've been going through Javascript function scope and have run into this:

```
var scope = "global";

function f(){
    console.log(scope);

    var scope = "local";

    console.log(scope);
}

f();
```

Now I understand that the output of the first log is "undefined" because of how js hoists variables at the top of the function. BUT when I remove var from "var scope = "local";" the first log outputs "global" and this has got me scratching my head. Can someone explain why that is happening please? I mean doesn't js sequentially run the code? As such how can removing VAR have any impact on the first log?

Comment: your var statement make "scope" local, hiding the global. once you define it, it becomes locally the string you set it to. due to var hoisting, your function is internally run as function f(){ var scope; ...

Comment: Hoisting hoisting hoisting... I'll try to find a duplicate question to point you to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange javascript scoping issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662458/strange-javascript-scoping-issue). See also: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-pass parsing. The code will be treated as if it was

```
function f() {
   var scope;  // var created, but no value assigned. this overrides the earlier global
   console.log(scope);
   scope = 'local';
   console.log(scope);
}
```

The var's CREATION will be executed as if it was the very first bit of code executed in the function. But the actual assignment operation won't occur until where it normally would.

Comment: Aha. So if i understand correctly, if I remove the variable declaration of variable scope, js will automagically hoist the variable to the top of the function. But if I declare it, then there is no need to hoist it and its scope is limited to the function?

Comment: doing `var scope` inside the f() function will create a new local variable whose name happens to match the one you defined as global outside the function. that new "inner" copy of scope will be the that's used in any "lower" scopes within f(). If you remove the `var` definition, then JS will simply use the 'global' copy, because you haven't hidden it with another more local copy. Read the article that @user2468852 has linked to down below. It's a very good writeup on what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript sometimes behaves a bit differently from other languages. Take a look at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html, they explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the var statement, the first log uses the global variable, which is set with the string "global". There is no other local variable and no hoisting.

1. First log: global variable scope set with "global" content
2. Assignment of new string for the same global variable
3. Second log: global variable scope set with "local" content