# How does putting 'module.exports = foo' work before foo is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I won't claim that I'm terribly well versed in Node, or even Javascript, but I've seen several modules of the form

```
module.exports = foo;

function foo() {
  ...
}
```

Now, I could see this working *perhaps* in this case, but I'm really confused when that module returns a function that is excuted.

```
module.exports = bar();

function bar() {
  ...
}
```

What is this witchcraft?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of NodeJS module.exports and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: @Mathletics No, I understand *what* it is, it's the order of operations that I didn't understand. I had looked at that question, but it didn't answer what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mathletics I've edited the title to more accurately reflect my question, and differentiate it further from the proposed duplicate. Please consider removing your vote to close.

Comment: Ah, got it. That's called _hoisting_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are javascript variables "hoisted" in these examples from MDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806135/how-are-javascript-variables-hoisted-in-these-examples-from-mdn)

Comment: @ithcy No, it's not related to that question at all. I honestly think you're just trolling.

Comment: I'm honestly *not* trolling and yes, it is exactly related to that question which explains variable hoisting in javascript just like the accepted answer to this question does.

Comment: They are related only in the sense that they're both about hoisting. The scenarios between the questions are completely different.

Comment: You asked "why does this happen?" The answer is "because hoisting." It has nothing to do with the scenarios, it's explained by a fundamental behavior of JavaScript.

Comment: I'm done feeding the trolls. I got my answer, so go ahead and close the question.

Comment: I'm not trolling just because you disagree with me. This is not a personal attack on you, this is just how duplicates on SO work. It takes 5 votes to close a question. If 4 other people agree with me then the question will be closed. If not, it won't. The end.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, though. It's a separate question. Fundamentally, they both ask questions that *relate* to hoisting. I was not *aware* of function hoisting at all, so my question is in a sense much broader, where the other question asks about a specific ordering or functionality of hoisting. They are not related. The end.

Comment: I think they are, but I can see your side, so I'll retract my close vote. Again, it's nothing personal. //Edit: retracted but there are still 2 close votes... not mine though :)

Comment: I appreciate the retracted vote. I apologize if my response in return seemed like a personal attack, I'm just tired of every question I ask being immediately closed. I mean, even before you it was voted for close for an entirely separate, and more distinctly unrelated duplicate.

Comment: No offense taken. I apologize if I was too hasty in my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions are defined at parse time, assignments are assigned at runtime. See this article http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/ for more.

In short, the compiler makes 2 passes. With the following code:

```
var a = x;
function x( ) { }
```

In the first pass, var a and function x are declared and available in a symbol table (or some other form depending on the interpreter) after which the compiler makes a second pass performing the assignment of function x as to var a. At this stage, at any point (but limited to the language rules), function x is known.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was going to ask for more clarification after I had seen your original answer, but the link you've provided was basically exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi This is often referred to as "function hoisting".  Might be helpful if you're trying to google it.